# UIContainerViews storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a normal UIViewController in my iPad storyboard. inside this viewcontroller I have other 2 UIcontainerViews, each linked up with another UIviewController (when I added the containerView, Xcode automatically created these 2 view controllers). I now have 2 view controller in the same view controller each wired up to a different class.

The only thing is that the views load and display the content (buttons, UITableview)...but the UITableView doesn't actually load the data, and when I press the buttons nothing happens. when I instead remove the container views and test the two ViewControllers separately, they work perfectly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had copied and pasted the content from one view controller to another, and even if the mach up's with the .h file where still there, they didn't work. I deleted all of the content and added it again